# How can I get my text that is displayed inline-block to wrap and increase the height of the parent container?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have an image and next to it a div with 2 child divs.  Both the image and container of the 2 divs are displayed inline-block.  The 2 divs contain a line of text.  I would like for the parent div to increase in height if the text overflows, but instead, the lines of text get pushed below the image.  Here are 2 examples.  In the first, the text is correctly aligned next to the image.  In the 2nd, the text gets pushed below the image because it overflows.

```css
.w-165{
  width: 165px;
}

.soft-border{
  border: solid 1px rgba(76, 84, 98, 0.3);
}

.h-70{
  height: 70px;
}

.d-inline-block{
  display: inline-block;
}

.align-middle{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-165 soft-border">
  <div class="soft-border">
    Notifications
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="h-70 d-inline-block align-middle" src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/9086/10h/s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Caterpillar/C820021?$cc-g$">
 <div class="d-inline-block align-middle">
   <div>
     New Issue
   </div>
   <div>
     Dec 15
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
</div>
```

```css
.w-165{
  width: 165px;
}

.soft-border{
  border: solid 1px rgba(76, 84, 98, 0.3);
}

.h-70{
  height: 70px;
}

.d-inline-block{
  display: inline-block;
}

.align-middle{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-165 soft-border">
  <div class="soft-border">
    Notifications
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="h-70 d-inline-block align-middle" src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/9086/10h/s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Caterpillar/C820021?$cc-g$">
 <div class="d-inline-block align-middle">
   <div>
     New Issues
   </div>
   <div>
     Dec 15
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do here is to define a width for the `div` in question. That will force text to wrap.

```
width: 60px;
```

Answer (score 1):

*One* of many solutions can be to use a *table layout* for your image and text container - so add this to your CSS:

```
.w-165 > div:last-child {
  display: table;
}
.w-165 > div:last-child > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
.w-165 {
  width: 165px;
}
.soft-border {
  border: solid 1px rgba(76, 84, 98, 0.3);
}
.h-70 {
  height: 70px;
}
.w-165 > div:last-child {
  display: table;
}
.w-165 > div:last-child > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
.d-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-165 soft-border">
  <div class="soft-border">
    Notifications
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="h-70 d-inline-block align-middle" src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/9086/10h/s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Caterpillar/C820021?$cc-g$">
    <div class="d-inline-block align-middle">
      <div>
        New Issues
      </div>
      <div>
        Dec 15
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to adjust the code for make it works as you wanted, check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ceocrg0o/4/).

> CSS

I had to add width to the `div`s to make the text wraps, of course with this solution if you enter a word that is too long it will get out of the `div`.

```
.h-70{
  width: 95px;
}

.d-inline-block div{
  width:60px;
}
```

Let me know if it helped please, thank you.